# King Solomon and Polygamy

Tags: shir-hashirim, king-solomon, polygamy

Why did Shlomo Hamelech marry many wives? Being that women naturally want to be the "only one"--from the fact that co-wives would fight each other for the love of their husband as the Mishna (Avot 2:7) says, "מרבה נשים מרבה כשפים (more wives=more witchcraft)" (thanks Fred for the source) and as the Talmud relates (co-wives are called tzarot, which relates to pain), as [Song of Songs 6.9](http://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.6) hints to, as evidenced by polygamy being [illegal in most of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_status_of_polygamy) under grounds of women's rights violations, as intuition and the spirit of the time shows, and as claimed by many women today through various forms of media--what reasoning would cause the "wisest of all men" to marry/love more than one wife?

(This question can apply to other righteous people like King David, but it is strongest in this case, because King Solomon may have known things that people in his and other generations did not. [Though the simple explanation is that every Jew knew about the Mishna in Avot and the negative outcome of such a marriage, so the question can be why anyone who would risk such a relationship]. Also, I am assuming that there were enough potential husbands available in Israel, because the Jews were wealthy during his era as stated in Book of Kings 1).

Comment: Many women would want to be queen, even if there were others.

Comment: Maybe because _he_ wanted multiple wives? None of your reasons related to his wishes

Comment: Consider that he may have had political motivations.

Comment: @ypnypn: I like that answer, but I wonder if women back then would really have wanted that deep down. If they wouldn't truly be happy, then I don't see why King Shlomo would do that.

Comment: Inasmuch as the question is a question, we could suggest that although most women want to be "the only one" wive of Shlomo were thrilled about the privilege of being his wife, even if it meant sharing him.

Comment: I don't quite see what the illegality of polygamy has to do with anything -- say it's illegal for another reason. [Immorality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmunds_Act), perhaps, was more of a driving factor than "what men and women want."

Comment: @Shokhet:Good point. Yet, why is it immoral? Is it not because of the friction it causes? It's a reasonable assumption. I've seen more utilitarian reasons, however, I am assuming there is more to it. Even without that point, the apparent nature and preference of most women cannot be ignored.

Comment: So then why do you need to reference modern day secular law at all? ...including that induces confusion about what your question is (*is he **really** blaming the Torah for not caring about 19th century American law??*) ....if your question is really based on the friction you think it causes, you might be better served by finding a simpler proof of that friction.

Comment: You are making an incorrect assumption about the intent behind my question. That's not my fault. I brought it in because I believe that if the world has evolved to think in an ethical way (as Harav Kook speaks about) then there may be something inherent about it. In this case, I believe that is fairly obvious, and is supported by our Torah tradition.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom For more Torah sources, see [*Pirkei Avos* 2:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%96) (מרבה נשים מרבה כשפים, which Rabbeinu Yonah ad loc. explains - borrowing some phrasing from P'nina's treatment of Chana - is due to the acrimonious competition that could result from polygamy), the [ban of Rabbeinu Gershom on polygamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_ben_Judah#Synod_and_bans), and the Torah's admonition that a king limit the number of his wives ([*D'varim* 17:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0517.htm#17)).

Answer (score 4):

As Fred pointed out, marrying a princess of Nation X was a form of diplomacy with Nation X. (And when all those princesses had their own houses with their own modes of worship, well, think embassies.) As he established peace and trade with lots and lots of other nations, well it may not have been good for personal happiness, but it served the national good.

If I recall correctly, Rabbi Menachem Leibtag discusses this in a lecture called: ["The Bible's Villains who Thought they were Heroes."](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/738566/Rabbi_Menachem_Leibtag/The_Bible%E2%80%99s_Villains_Who_Thought_They_Were_Heroes_)

Comment: Did the princesses have a say in the matter, or were they forced into the marriages by their parents?

Comment: Also, did Shlomo have many wives or were they just concubines? Does the prohibition of >18 wives apply to concubines?

Comment: I guess even if they were forced, they would be forced to marry someone else anyway, so Shlomo decided it would be best that they marry him (which didn't seem to be the best decision as we see they continued in their idolatrous ways)

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom 700 wives and 300 concubines ([*M'lachim* I 11:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a11.htm#3)). He was criticized for disobeying the halacha not to have an excessive number of wives ([*Sanhedrin* 21b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=21b&format=text)).

Comment: Source.........

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom I'd assume it's much like how the British royal family does military service and charitable work -- you grow up with the understanding that it's one of your responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

It writes in Batei Midrashos 2:451 that Shlomo took 1000 wives so that he would have a thousand sons a year, thereby making twenty thousand in twenty years. In so doing, no one would be able to overpower him.

Comment: If that was his plan, then it completely backfired... From Koheles 6:3 (אם יוליד איש מאה) it seems that he didn't have even a hundred children!

Comment: Interesting - good shout!

Answer (score 0):

Solomon had 1000 women. 700 wives, and 300 concubines. As we know from Megillat Esther (and other sources), there are 70 nations of the world. Solomon would marry 10 women from each of the 70 nations. The 300 concubines are the women who Solomon took from his own nation. By doing this, he hoped to ally himself with all the nations of the world.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these statements? If yes please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/68320/edit) them in. If not you might see your answers downvoted which would be a pity as you seem there is quite a bit you could contribute here. See my comment on your previous post for some links to help you understand MY

Comment: @Cosman. Your answer is purely speculative, even wildly so.